# How to run ajax process first before calling slider on vue component?

Tags: vue.js, slider, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

My top league component vue like this :

```
<template>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3" v-for="item in items">
             <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-image">
                    <a :href="baseUrl+'/leagues/'+item.id+'/'+item.name"
                        :style="{backgroundImage: 'url(' + baseUrl + '/img/leagues/'+item.photo+ ')'}">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    ...
    export default {
        ...
        props: ['leagueId'],
        mounted(){
            setTimeout( function(){  
                $('.slick').not('.slick-initialized').slick({slidesToShow: 3, infinite: false});
            }  , 10000 );
        },
        created() {
            this.getTopLeague([{league_id: this.leagueId}]) // this is ajax if load first
        },
        computed: {
            ...mapGetters([
                'getListLeague'
            ]),
            items() {
                const n = ['getListLeague']
                return this[n[0]] // this is response ajax // exist 5 league
            }
        },
        methods: {
            ...mapActions([
                'getTopLeague'
            ])
        }
    }
</script>
```

When loaded the first time, there are 5 items of data displayed in the form of sliders. And the slider works. I use setTimeout. But, it does not seem to be an effective way. Because the ajax process is completed sometimes not until 10 seconds. Sometimes only 2-5 seconds. And that's uncertain.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

[`mapActions` maps your actions to `store.dispatch`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/actions.html), which [returns a promise](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/api.html). You should be able to simply wait for the promise to resolve and then do your callback:

```
export default {
    ...
    props: ['leagueId'],
    created() {
        this.getTopLeague([{league_id: this.leagueId}])
            .then(function(){  
                $('.slick').not('.slick-initialized').slick({slidesToShow: 3, infinite: false});
            })
    },
    ...
```

Comment: There exist error : `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: $(...).not(...).slick is not a function`

Comment: That's telling you that `slick` isn't attached to the jQuery instance you're referencing. It's surprising you're not seeing that in the timeout. Possible causes: 1. The getTopLeague() call is returning faster than the slick library loads 2. You've somehow managed to import 2 jQuery instances, and one of them hasn't had the slick library installed.

Comment: I load the library slick in gulpfile

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using an Ajax framework like [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios), or [Vue-Resource](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-resource) and then wait for the server to respond before triggering your code.

```
axios.get(url)
.then( res => {
  //your code.
})
```